# How to speed-up Geth transactions in private blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, web3j, geth-debugging

I'm testing Ethereum smart contracts with `web3j` and `Geth`.
Geth is running with scripts like that:

```
PASSFILE=/var/folders/_l/kl9pdj2x50v7416j8htb6w740000gn/T/pwd6597172766860806720.tmp
DATADIR=/var/folders/_l/kl9pdj2x50v7416j8htb6w740000gn/T/geth808290308908087582
IPCPATH=/var/folders/_l/kl9pdj2x50v7416j8htb6w740000gn/T/geth808290308908087582/geth.ipc

geth --datadir $DATADIR account new --password $PASSFILE
geth --datadir $DATADIR \
    --ipcpath $IPCPATH \
    --dev \
    --rpc \
    --mine \
    --networkid 1999
```

(paths are generated in tests).

Smart contract wrappers are generated with `web3j-maven-plugin`.

The problem is that every `send()` invocation takes few seconds:

```
private TransactionReceipt deployFeature_() throws Exception {
    logger.info("Deploying feature ...");
    return contract.deployFeature(featureKey).send();
}
```

log (you can see 1 transaction took 16 seconds):

```
166955 [main] INFO FeatureTest - Deploying feature ...
182006 [main] INFO FeatureTest - Checking feature is listed ...
```

Web3j is connected over IPC:

```
web3 = Web3j.build(new UnixIpcService(ipcPath));
```

How can i speed-up invocations? If testing with `TestRPC` every invocations takes much less than a second! Since `Geth` is started with `--dev` it generates genesis file itself so i can't change difficulty. Also i can see blocks are mined very fast:

```
INFO [11-09|00:34:39] Commit new mining work                   number=9 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=2.000s
INFO [11-09|00:34:39] Successfully sealed new block            number=9 hash=b869ca…870644
INFO [11-09|00:34:39]  block reached canonical chain          number=4 hash=c758a0…a529af
INFO [11-09|00:34:39]  mined potential block                  number=9 hash=b869ca…870644
INFO [11-09|00:34:39] Commit new mining work                   number=10 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=84.12µs
INFO [11-09|00:34:40] Successfully sealed new block            number=10 hash=5e81a9…fc1364
INFO [11-09|00:34:40]  block reached canonical chain          number=5  hash=465c2b…78461a
INFO [11-09|00:34:40]  mined potential block                  number=10 hash=5e81a9…fc1364
```

For some reason invocations are not fast. What can i do?

Update 1: verbose geth log:

```
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:24] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
TRACE[11-09|10:55:24] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=2704551168899111732
TRACE[11-09|10:55:24] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=5467839612232628274
TRACE[11-09|10:55:24] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=1157694161266147191
TRACE[11-09|10:55:24] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=7845452550729559273
TRACE[11-09|10:55:25] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=3 attempts=33111  nonce=2704551168899144843
TRACE[11-09|10:55:25] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=1 attempts=33196
TRACE[11-09|10:55:25] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=2 attempts=34566
TRACE[11-09|10:55:25] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=29434
INFO [11-09|10:55:25] Successfully sealed new block            number=135 hash=7cbd94…37dc26
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:25] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=38 unloads=3
INFO [11-09|10:55:25]  block reached canonical chain          number=130 hash=3ca7c4…374497
INFO [11-09|10:55:25]  mined potential block                  number=135 hash=7cbd94…37dc26
TRACE[11-09|10:55:25] Propagated block                         hash=7cbd94…37dc26 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:25] Announced block                          hash=7cbd94…37dc26 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:25] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
INFO [11-09|10:55:25] Commit new mining work                   number=136 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=297.987µs
TRACE[11-09|10:55:25] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=5487602165862729957
TRACE[11-09|10:55:25] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=1373940052212025290
TRACE[11-09|10:55:25] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=2640498343526987028
TRACE[11-09|10:55:25] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=7750561880638031679
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=3 attempts=91684  nonce=5487602165862821641
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=84642
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=1 attempts=88714
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=2 attempts=89722
INFO [11-09|10:55:26] Successfully sealed new block            number=136 hash=63b459…f7943d
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:26] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=38 unloads=3
INFO [11-09|10:55:26]  block reached canonical chain          number=131 hash=f3baed…7b4cd1
INFO [11-09|10:55:26]  mined potential block                  number=136 hash=63b459…f7943d
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Propagated block                         hash=63b459…f7943d recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Announced block                          hash=63b459…f7943d recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:26] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
INFO [11-09|10:55:26] Commit new mining work                   number=137 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=137µs
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=5735737036966792397
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=2201918865350132270
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=7114248001329383901
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=7064937725018178156
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=1 attempts=306    nonce=7114248001329384207
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=2 attempts=215
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=337
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=213
INFO [11-09|10:55:26] Successfully sealed new block            number=137 hash=bfebbd…7bebbb
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:26] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=38 unloads=3
INFO [11-09|10:55:26]  block reached canonical chain          number=132 hash=cc2b57…a1eaa2
INFO [11-09|10:55:26]  mined potential block                  number=137 hash=bfebbd…7bebbb
INFO [11-09|10:55:26] Mining too far in the future             wait=2s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Propagated block                         hash=bfebbd…7bebbb recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:26] Announced block                          hash=bfebbd…7bebbb recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:26] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
INFO [11-09|10:55:28] Commit new mining work                   number=138 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=2.004s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=1224837056936865954
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=4158743884218822112
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=8186530166650094269
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=6717769196178392649
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=2 attempts=42268  nonce=6717769196178434917
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=42660
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=41386
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=1 attempts=41693
INFO [11-09|10:55:28] Successfully sealed new block            number=138 hash=45b114…b0a64c
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:28] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=38 unloads=3
INFO [11-09|10:55:28]  block reached canonical chain          number=133 hash=8bf749…99d498
INFO [11-09|10:55:28]  mined potential block                  number=138 hash=45b114…b0a64c
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Propagated block                         hash=45b114…b0a64c recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Announced block                          hash=45b114…b0a64c recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:28] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
INFO [11-09|10:55:28] Commit new mining work                   number=139 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=270.413µs
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=3768964950495190140
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=5926649220579239325
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=3891061113576232214
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=5321048005196544766
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=1 attempts=21588  nonce=3891061113576253802
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=23462
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=2 attempts=20734
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=22319
INFO [11-09|10:55:28] Successfully sealed new block            number=139 hash=044ca7…613598
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:28] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=38 unloads=3
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Propagated block                         hash=044ca7…613598 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:28] Announced block                          hash=044ca7…613598 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
INFO [11-09|10:55:28]  block reached canonical chain          number=134 hash=d838f4…cee2bb
INFO [11-09|10:55:28]  mined potential block                  number=139 hash=044ca7…613598
INFO [11-09|10:55:28] Mining too far in the future             wait=2s
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:28] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:29] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
INFO [11-09|10:55:30] Commit new mining work                   number=140 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=2.005s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:30] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=2431275746132954900
TRACE[11-09|10:55:30] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=133342005747271086
TRACE[11-09|10:55:30] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=868361158371692178
TRACE[11-09|10:55:30] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=5249231453164485083
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=2 attempts=62517  nonce=5249231453164547600
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=62189
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=1 attempts=63614
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=69187
INFO [11-09|10:55:31] Successfully sealed new block            number=140 hash=03dd70…e52a0d
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:31] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=38 unloads=3
INFO [11-09|10:55:31]  block reached canonical chain          number=135 hash=7cbd94…37dc26
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Propagated block                         hash=03dd70…e52a0d recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Announced block                          hash=03dd70…e52a0d recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
INFO [11-09|10:55:31]  mined potential block                  number=140 hash=03dd70…e52a0d
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:31] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
INFO [11-09|10:55:31] Commit new mining work                   number=141 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=114.636µs
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=276478866435324212
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=6717522840261329056
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=5244579135382777440
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=2008888944128372975
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=1 attempts=11239  nonce=276478866435335451
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=12957
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=2 attempts=12635
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=10361
INFO [11-09|10:55:31] Successfully sealed new block            number=141 hash=f70e67…2e32f2
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:31] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=38 unloads=3
INFO [11-09|10:55:31]  block reached canonical chain          number=136 hash=63b459…f7943d
INFO [11-09|10:55:31]  mined potential block                  number=141 hash=f70e67…2e32f2
INFO [11-09|10:55:31] Commit new mining work                   number=142 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=123.645µs
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Propagated block                         hash=f70e67…2e32f2 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Announced block                          hash=f70e67…2e32f2 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:31] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=8374694286219227537
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=5525441204149154275
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=5050633008585803076
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=5994448739100426473
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=0 attempts=4285   nonce=5994448739100430758
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=3993
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=2 attempts=3740
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=1 attempts=6189
INFO [11-09|10:55:31] Successfully sealed new block            number=142 hash=aae188…c079bb
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:31] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=38 unloads=3
INFO [11-09|10:55:31]  block reached canonical chain          number=137 hash=bfebbd…7bebbb
INFO [11-09|10:55:31]  mined potential block                  number=142 hash=aae188…c079bb
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:31] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Propagated block                         hash=aae188…c079bb recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:31] Announced block                          hash=aae188…c079bb recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
INFO [11-09|10:55:31] Mining too far in the future             wait=2s
INFO [11-09|10:55:33] Commit new mining work                   number=143 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=2.004s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:33] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=5169074969181971547
TRACE[11-09|10:55:33] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=452169367209038574
TRACE[11-09|10:55:33] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=5956945769096062545
TRACE[11-09|10:55:33] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=2025226096662640179
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=2 attempts=7973   nonce=2025226096662648152
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=8043
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=1 attempts=6665
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=8321
INFO [11-09|10:55:34] Successfully sealed new block            number=143 hash=b91839…9bcd57
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:34] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=38 unloads=3
INFO [11-09|10:55:34]  block reached canonical chain          number=138 hash=45b114…b0a64c
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Propagated block                         hash=b91839…9bcd57 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Announced block                          hash=b91839…9bcd57 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
INFO [11-09|10:55:34]  mined potential block                  number=143 hash=b91839…9bcd57
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:34] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
INFO [11-09|10:55:34] Commit new mining work                   number=144 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=331.063µs
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=285769866382517826
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=4211212444297990109
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=7004332557753625929
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=7813145494318450621
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=0 attempts=37990  nonce=285769866382555816
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=1 attempts=41488
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=2 attempts=41885
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=39940
INFO [11-09|10:55:34] Successfully sealed new block            number=144 hash=90e685…1fa3ba
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:34] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=38 unloads=3
INFO [11-09|10:55:34]  block reached canonical chain          number=139 hash=044ca7…613598
INFO [11-09|10:55:34]  mined potential block                  number=144 hash=90e685…1fa3ba
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Propagated block                         hash=90e685…1fa3ba recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Announced block                          hash=90e685…1fa3ba recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:34] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
INFO [11-09|10:55:34] Commit new mining work                   number=145 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=159.903µs
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=5829638230506590037
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=1575797057955125519
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=4259186434366596182
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=8406925385514726032
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=1 attempts=31101  nonce=5829638230506621138
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=32654
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=30571
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=2 attempts=32876
INFO [11-09|10:55:34] Successfully sealed new block            number=145 hash=9a1563…352fd8
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:34] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=38 unloads=3
INFO [11-09|10:55:34]  block reached canonical chain          number=140 hash=03dd70…e52a0d
INFO [11-09|10:55:34]  mined potential block                  number=145 hash=9a1563…352fd8
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:34] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
INFO [11-09|10:55:34] Mining too far in the future             wait=2s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Propagated block                         hash=9a1563…352fd8 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:34] Announced block                          hash=9a1563…352fd8 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
INFO [11-09|10:55:36] Commit new mining work                   number=146 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=2.004s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:36] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=8286615947492221141
TRACE[11-09|10:55:36] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=8741615336398335994
TRACE[11-09|10:55:36] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=4669180278364899564
TRACE[11-09|10:55:36] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=7148111501866672766
TRACE[11-09|10:55:36] Pooled new future transaction            hash=b9bbcd…d3707a from=0x4861F79070597b9aC1C254CA2Ed60A529Dd2e389 to=0xB1B74d101f884B096a61D81Be872313C1B7fe3d5
TRACE[11-09|10:55:36] Promoting queued transaction             hash=b9bbcd…d3707a
INFO [11-09|10:55:36] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0xb9bbcd667e4ed74ffdf05fe160c3b22f0fe649bb72c77ccf1aed42fe88d3707a recipient=0xB1B74d101f884B096a61D81Be872313C1B7fe3d5
TRACE[11-09|10:55:36] Broadcast transaction                    hash=b9bbcd…d3707a recipients=0
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=2 attempts=14067  nonce=8741615336398350061
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=14680
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=12633
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=1 attempts=11797
INFO [11-09|10:55:37] Successfully sealed new block            number=146 hash=9cae54…158806
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:37] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=38 unloads=3
INFO [11-09|10:55:37]  block reached canonical chain          number=141 hash=f70e67…2e32f2
INFO [11-09|10:55:37]  mined potential block                  number=146 hash=9cae54…158806
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:37] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Propagated block                         hash=9cae54…158806 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Announced block                          hash=9cae54…158806 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
INFO [11-09|10:55:37] Commit new mining work                   number=147 txs=1 uncles=0 elapsed=387.009µs
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=7566020767740453247
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=5884659729515644343
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=1071774666687042399
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=2002936964839990580
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=1 attempts=1515   nonce=5884659729515645858
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=61
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=2 attempts=100
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=722
INFO [11-09|10:55:37] Successfully sealed new block            number=147 hash=5fc288…c85458
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:37] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=43 unloads=5
INFO [11-09|10:55:37]  block reached canonical chain          number=142 hash=aae188…c079bb
INFO [11-09|10:55:37]  mined potential block                  number=147 hash=5fc288…c85458
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Propagated block                         hash=5fc288…c85458 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Announced block                          hash=5fc288…c85458 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:37] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Removed old pending transaction          hash=b9bbcd…d3707a
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Skipping transaction with low nonce      sender=0x4861F79070597b9aC1C254CA2Ed60A529Dd2e389 nonce=3
INFO [11-09|10:55:37] Commit new mining work                   number=148 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=675.189µs
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=3958501350403479078
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=6203768588880501513
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=5064820792710835590
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=5412274811189968416
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=2 attempts=13335  nonce=5064820792710848925
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=16363
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=1 attempts=15195
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=14805
INFO [11-09|10:55:37] Successfully sealed new block            number=148 hash=a2f133…7d3c3a
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:37] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=43 unloads=5
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Propagated block                         hash=a2f133…7d3c3a recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:37] Announced block                          hash=a2f133…7d3c3a recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
INFO [11-09|10:55:37]  block reached canonical chain          number=143 hash=b91839…9bcd57
INFO [11-09|10:55:37]  mined potential block                  number=148 hash=a2f133…7d3c3a
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:37] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
INFO [11-09|10:55:37] Mining too far in the future             wait=2s
INFO [11-09|10:55:39] Commit new mining work                   number=149 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=2.003s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=9004437381227325005
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=4677894406148947982
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=4282958466159618226
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=5473315208039867250
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=1 attempts=2608   nonce=4677894406148950590
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=2 attempts=3102
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=2995
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=2149
INFO [11-09|10:55:39] Successfully sealed new block            number=149 hash=2c3ef8…a77061
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:39] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=43 unloads=5
INFO [11-09|10:55:39]  block reached canonical chain          number=144 hash=90e685…1fa3ba
INFO [11-09|10:55:39]  mined potential block                  number=149 hash=2c3ef8…a77061
INFO [11-09|10:55:39] Commit new mining work                   number=150 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=130.236µs
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Propagated block                         hash=2c3ef8…a77061 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Announced block                          hash=2c3ef8…a77061 recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=3 seed=1397362054021317308
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=1 seed=8416565765969603762
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:39] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=2 seed=8261865379882237351
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Started ethash search for new nonces     miner=0 seed=38264667837276317
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Ethash nonce found and reported          miner=2 attempts=49915  nonce=8261865379882287266
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=1 attempts=48727
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=0 attempts=51358
TRACE[11-09|10:55:39] Ethash nonce search aborted              miner=3 attempts=52728
INFO [11-09|10:55:39] Successfully sealed new block            number=150 hash=b1ea6e…b8382e
DEBUG[11-09|10:55:39] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=43 unloads=5
INFO [11-09|10:55:39]  block reached canonical chain          number=145 hash=9a1563…352fd8
```

Comment: you should first check who is delaying. enable debug.verbosity(6) and check exact execution time of geth.

Comment: i've started geth with `--minerthreads 4` and `--verbosity 6`, see verbose log in updated Question. I've started multiple tests so probably you can see multiple transactions. What should i find in the log? Can you see something can be adjusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `web3j` feature/issue and you can change this behaviour: https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/231